# Can this be done in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a buyernumber from a SQL table. Doesn't seem to want to pull the information out of the table though.

Here is what I have:

I have a variable:

newItemNum = 7962525;

I have a table in my sql database that has 2 columns, itemnumber and buyernumber.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from %buyer%_%supplier%xref where Itemnumber LIKE 'newItemNum%';"
```

The itemnumber in the table is: 7962525 Movie Set

It's going into the table and not finding anything.

Comment: Are you saying that the itemnumber is actually a string value of "7962525 Movie Set"?

Comment: What is the name of the table?

Comment: is this really Microsoft SQL Server or is it MySQL

Comment: The name of the table is Costco_HomeDepotxref. It shows that when I hit run and check what StrSQL is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from %buyer%_%supplier%xref where Itemnumber LIKE 'newItemNum%';"
```

To

```
strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from %buyer%_%supplier%xref where Itemnumber LIKE '"+newItemNum+"%';"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LIKE 'newItemNum%'
```

is a literal match. you have to parameterize newItemNum

```
LIKE @newItemNum + '%'
```

or if you don't wanna mess with params, do this:

```
strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from %buyer%_%supplier%xref where Itemnumber LIKE '" + newItemNum + "%';"
```

EDIT:

If you're dynamically acquiring table names use something like this:

```
var buyer="Costco";
var supplier="HomeDepot";
var newItemNum="123445656";

var strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from " +buyer+ "_" + supplier + "xref where Itemnumber LIKE '" + newItemNum + "%';"
```

Comment: Still getting an error. It wont let me use that line of code. I get the error "Substitution %Variable% not followed by a % (Use %% for %)"

Comment: That's probably due to weird table name you're using. What is the table name? It can't include % signs so, it must be buyer_supplier_xref (or some other variation). Just make sure to use correct table name.

Comment: It is the right table name, when I run the program and check what strsql is equal to I get Costco_HomeDepotxref for my table name.

Comment: So use that, instead of %%buyer%_%supplier%. If you're dynamically populating the table name, again, change the string to correctly concatenate values. See my edit

Comment: I probably should of mentioned that I'm using Winbatch Studio to right the code. And it doesn't pick up the variables when I do + newItemNum +

Comment: Okay... Sorry couldn't help, but I think would be better if you post the question to their forums.

Comment: It's okay thanks for the help. I actually figured it out! It's strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from %buyer%_%supplier%xref where Itemnumber LIKE '%newItemNum%%%';"

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL string needs to use a variable.  Replace

```
strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from %buyer%_%supplier%xref where Itemnumber LIKE 'newItemNum%';"
```

with

```
strSQL = "select BuyerNumber from %buyer%_%supplier%xref where Itemnumber LIKE @newItemNum + '%';"
```

Comment: Still getting an error. It wont let me use that line of code. I get the error "Substitution %Variable% not followed by a % (Use %% for %)"

Comment: Try Mind Hunter Photon's answer, his is actually probably better.  If that doesn't work, let me know.